# Bernoulli number type asymptotics

Tags: asymptotics, definite-integrals, special-functions, analytic-number-theory

I find an interesting formula but I can not prove it. Show that
$$I_n=(-1)^{n+1}\int_0^1 B_{2n+1}(x)\cot(\pi x) \, dx\sim\frac{2(2n+1)!}{(2\pi)^{2n+1}}$$
where $B_n(x)$ is the Bernoulli Polynomials.

Comment: You've got a function of $x$ equal to an expression in which $x$ is a bound variable, so it's a quantity that doesn't depend on anything called $x$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy:Thanks, this is just a trivial matter, I think. What I care about is the matter itself.

Answer (score 5):

According to Corollary 1 of [[1]](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021904587900712),

$$
(-1)^{n+1} \frac{(2\pi)^{2n+1}}{2(2n+1)!} B_{2n+1}(x) \longrightarrow \sin(2\pi x)
$$

uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$.  It follows that

$$
\begin{align}
(-1)^{n+1} \frac{(2\pi)^{2n+1}}{2(2n+1)!} \int_0^1 B_{2n+1}(x) \cot(\pi x)\,dx &\to
 \int_0^1 \sin(2\pi x)\cot(\pi x)\,dx \\
&= 2\int_0^1 \sin(\pi x)\cos(\pi x)\cot(\pi x)\,dx \\
&= 1,
\end{align}
$$

and so

$$
(-1)^{n+1} \int_0^1 B_{2n+1}(x) \cot(\pi x)\,dx \sim \frac{2(2n+1)!}{(2\pi)^{2n+1}}
$$

as $n \to \infty$.

---

**[1]** Dilcher, K.  *Asymptotic behaviour of Bernoulli, Euler, and generalized Bernoulli polynomials.*  ([ScienceDirect link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021904587900712))