# An integral relating to Bernoulli polynomials

Tags: asymptotics, definite-integrals, special-functions

Show that
$$\int_{0}^{1}B_{2n+1}(x)(\cot({\pi}x)-2\sin(2{\pi}x))dx{\sim}0$$
where $B_{2n+1}(x)$ is the Bernoulli polynomials.

Comment: Why? Where does the question come from, please? What reason do you have for thinking it's true? What progress have you made on it? What relevant facts do you know?

Comment: Do you mean $\to 0$ instead of $\sim 0$?  And, numerically, this does not seem to be true.  [Here's a plot](http://i.imgur.com/oFCs6UG.png) of the absolute value of the integral made with Mathematica.

Comment: @AntonioVargas. I wonder if there is a problem in your calculations. For n=1, I get 0.00977497; for n=2, -0.000905034; for n=3, 0.000217696; for n=4, -0.0000955043; for n=5, 0.0000654787. For sure, the error can be on my side !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, there certainly could be, but my calculations agree with the ones you've given for $n=1,2,3,4,5$.  Try it again for $n=15$, I get $\approx 1.3821255$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas. You are perfectly right and I apologize. I stopped too early these calculations which take a lot of time.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, no need to apologize, I'm happy someone else was double checking!  Mathematica's routines are kind of a mystery to me so I'm never sure if the result they give is reality or fiction.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is false.  To show this we'll use a stronger estimate than the one used in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/561976/5531) to your last question.

In equation $(2.11)$ of [this paper (ScienceDirect link)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X09006878) the author gives the Fourier expansion

$$
B_{2n+1}(x) = 2(-1)^{n+1} (2n+1)! \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2\pi k x)}{(2\pi k)^{2n+1}},
$$

which also serves as an asymptotic expansion when $n \to \infty$.

Integrating over only the first two terms yields

$$
\int_0^1 B_{2n+1}(x) (\cot(\pi x) - 2\sin(2\pi x))\,dx \sim (-1)^{n+1} \frac{2(2n+1)!}{(4\pi)^{2n+1}},
$$

which does not tend to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Here's a plot over the range $1 \leq n \leq 30$ with a logarithmic scale on the vertical axis, comparing the absolute values of the integral evaluated numerically (blue dots) and this asymptotic (red line).

[image]